# New inserted data must show first

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have some products inside this table:

```
Id | Name | Order
------------------
3 | Prod3 | 1
2 | Prod2 | 2
1 | Prod1 | 3
```

What I need is: when adding some new product that new product should be the first one ordered by 'order' (INT), like this:

```
Id | Name | Order
------------------
4 | NewPr | 1    
3 | Prod3 | 2
2 | Prod2 | 3
1 | Prod1 | 4
```

This means the others should be: *previous order* + 1

How achieve that with SQL?

---

Currently I'm doing this (the opposite of what I need now):

Before insert, get the last order number

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `order` FROM `products` ORDER BY `order` DESC LIMIT 1");
while($orderData = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $lastOrder = $orderData['order'];
};
$newOrder = $lastOrder + 1;
```

Adding the new product

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`name`, `order`)
VALUES ('MyLastestProd', $newOrder)
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I use those numbers because in other page I have a draggable option for re-order those products.

**EDIT 2:** Solved displaying the products ordering by 'order' DESC. So using *previous order* + 1 it's useful for me. Changes applied to the UI draggable feature too.

Comment: Insert the record with an "order" of 0 and then update all records to increment "order" by 1?

Comment: This kind of problem typically occurs when someone tries to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @david How can I increment all records without slowing down the proccess?

Comment: that would mean for every insert, you have to update your *complete* table. if you have hopes of your software being successful, i can guarantee you that this will result in an outrageous performance issue. imagine a 10'000-row-table - your DBMS has 10'000-times the work to do. so your idea is definitely *not* the way to go. couldn't you instead order by a timestamp or something?

Comment: @strawberry Please explain.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro: What do you mean by "slowing down the process"?  If you want to update every record, then the database is going to update every record.  If that takes a lot of time then I guess you'd need to fine-tune the database.  It's a single query, so PHP doesn't really have anything to do with the performance.  There's a good chance that you can achieve this same sorting logic with something that *doesn't* involve updating every record every time...

Comment: Just store the date. Problem solved.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro Do the records ever need to be re-ordered?

Comment: @mike Yep, I edited my question for remark that.

Comment: Is the **id** `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  In this case you can just sort by id DESC.

Comment: @moni-dragu Must be reordered-friendly.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro Maybe ``INSERT INTO `products` (`name`, `order`)
VALUES ('MyLastestProd', (SELECT MAX(`order`) + 1 FROM `products))`` and then sort them `DESC` instead of `ASC` when displaying them.

Comment: While everybody is debating clever ways to approach this, have you actually measured what's involved in updating all of the records to increment by 1?  Does it noticeably impact performance on any reasonable volume of data?  Other than "it might not be the perfect solution in all possible cases", is there a concrete reason not to do it?  Failing that, could the "add the new one at the top" requirement be moved to a *UI* concern instead of a *data* concern?  So new records are temporarily added to the top until the user specifies the sort order?

Comment: @david You are totally right; it's expected to be a 1000+ records in some months. The _solution_ of adding the new product with 'order' = 0 it's a little bit complicated when an user inserts a new product before the previous new one and then I have two zero-order values in two new products. And it's not gonna change until the user re-order the products from the UI draggable feature.

Comment: I still think you should add the new products with a greater `order` and then sort it the other way around. This way the only time you would ever have to increment many values is when the products are reordered, and it would only be those whose order is between the one being dragged and the position being dropped.

Comment: @mike Yep, I've thinking about that. Which means I need to re-order all the products now before upload more. Damn.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro That's pretty easy. Just find the max order and ``UPDATE products SET `order` = {max_order} - `order` ``. Poof.

Comment: @mike Thanks! I simulated this query in PHPMyAdmin and get an error: `UPDATE products SET order = MAX(order) - order` (#1111 - Invalid use of group function) .

Comment: Make sure you put backticks around `\`order\``. It's a reserved word in mysql. Also, you should put the max value in manually because it can change half way through. Then you're going to have a real mess. Maybe back up first too :)

Comment: @mike Maybe we should move this to a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126246/discussion-between-jimmy-adaro-and-mike).

Comment: Finally solved with displaying the products in order DESC.

Comment: The title and the question no longer match up, so how's anyone supposed to know which question is (supposed to be) being answered?

Answer (score 3):

Would an easier way to achieve this would be to change your Order table column to a timestamp field called 'DateAdded' with a default value of 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

Then when inserting a new row into your table you do not have to give it an order at all, when selecting the rows from your table just:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY DateAdded DESC
```

This approach would be much easier on execution time rather than having to update every row in the table.

Out of interest, why do you have to have a new inserted row at the very top?
If you're trying to just select the latest row you already have an ID column which i assume is a primary key with the auto_increment attribute set?

So, why not just use the ID column as your sorting column in select queries?

**EDIT**

Just seen your edit, i see now.

You could use both a date field and an order field to do double-sorting in your query.

For example:
If every new product you add has an order value of zero, and a timestamp recorded next to it, you can still order these correctly and still allow users to re-order them as well.

Comment: The most recent question edit indicates that there needs to be a user-friendly dynamic sort.  (User-specified ordering)

Comment: Please read the edit note; this system uses a draggable re-order for those products. So I guess I can't re-order the _timestamp_.

Comment: Or that he marks his order column as auto increment

Comment: @Imaginaroom - no point,he has his ID field doing that already.

Comment: @imaginaroom A_I means that the new product is going to be _last order_ + 1, something that now I try to avoid.

Comment: You could also add another column for the creation date of the record, and maybe a modification date too. It's a good practice

Comment: @sebcar How can that be useful for this _re-order thing_ issue? I mean, yeah, it's a good practice for showing that data to the system administrator.

Comment: You don't need to re order, you need to show a item list in the order you want like in the example written by @MarkPhillips

Comment: SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY DateAdded DESC, Order DESC

This should be enough to get what you want, either that or two SQL queries - one where it selects everything where order = 0 order by DateAdded, and another one where it selects everything where order != 0 order by order

Comment: I have over-complicated this. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Yes. If you need a field 'order' to use in the UI, you can added in PHP manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO products (name, order) VALUES 
('MyLastestProd', (select count(a.order)+1 as new_order from products a order by a.order desc limit 1));
```

So, when you select your product you can use

```
select *from products as p order by p.order desc
```

Comment: That's add +1 to the new product's value, which is the opposite of what I'm need help with.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro i have edited my answer. you can use `count(a.order+1)`